# RXTX getPortIdentifiers not finding ports on Mac OSx

Tags: macos, arduino, java-7, rxtx

I've spent most of my weekend trying to connect to my Arduino over the serial/usb port using Java.

I went through a bunch of different tutorials but I cannot find a solution the problem I am running into.

First of, I am running Java 7 on Mavericks. I downloaded the librxtxSerial.jnilib from the iharder blog (that also supports 64 bit) and used the JAR that comes with my functioning Arduino IDE.

The program runs fine and gets no errors, however, when trying to find the right port it turns out my program finds no ports at all.

```
CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
```

returns no ports at all.

When I check on my mac using

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

I get a nice list of ports including the on my Arduino is running on.

SO although my program gives me no errors, it simply does not seem to find the ports. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using cut'n'paste of the `SerialTest.java` class from Arduino Playground page. Problem went away when I commented out

```
// System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev//ttyACM0");
```

Hope this helps.